# Can I disable Google Web Light for my website?

Tags: php, android, html, css

When i open my website using google it opens with google web light and my site looks ugly, is there any way to disable the google web light, is there any disadvantage of doing that ?

Help me !
Thanks in advance !

Comment: If you do not want your pages to be transcoded, set the HTTP header "Cache-Control: no-transform" in your page response. If Googlebot sees this header, your page will not be transcoded.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6211428?hl=en

Comment: @GermanoPlebani how to do do that, what code should i add, will i have to add the code in all the pages, can i do it with .htaccess ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php header("Cache-Control: no-transform"); ?>
```

Just add this code to your Html files 
Disadvantage of doing this:
1)It would result in a warning sign showing that the site is slow to load which might result in decreasing your viewership.

2)Google Adsense isn't disabled in the light version however the aesthetics and location of the ads would change which might result in decreased income but keeping that in mind the user has a slow internet connection you aren't going through that much of a loss.

Comment: i just added this code in my three pages which is crawled by search engines, but still it opens in the same google weblight !

Comment: Did your try  changing its extension from .html to .php

Comment: i have saved all the pages with .php extension, i think google take some time to crawl it aging, am i right ?

Comment: http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=[your_website_URL.  Check your website on this URL it will show live result

Answer (score 0):

This Google help document describes how to have your site opt-out of Google Web Light:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6211428?hl=en

If you do not want your pages to be transcoded, set the HTTP header Cache-Control: no-transform in your page response. If Googlebot sees this header, your page will not be transcoded.

Please note that pages that opt-out of being transcoded will be labeled in search results to indicate to users that they may take longer to load and may use more data.