# How to disable google web light for the website

Tags: google-api, meta-tags, google-website-optimizer, google-web-designer, google-web-component

When i am opening my website in slow internet connection then google provide google web light feature then website loading faster. But website is not properly aligned. And load ugly website. I want to disable google web light for the website.

> I am using for "no-transform" the disable :

```html
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-transform" />
```

I don't know this right approach or not? And how to check it google web light disabled or not. Because google automatically detect some time load normal user interface and some time load ugly(WITH GOOGLE WEB LIGHT) user interface. 
Give me some idea for this..thanks.

I am tested website with in  https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/transcoder?pli=1#url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.winni.in%2Fbangalore

I have seen one link [Can I disable Google Web Light for my website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/88703/can-i-disable-google-web-light-for-my-website) And also putted  `<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-transform">` in header but it is not working.

Comment: Try to add this in your server **response** (not in the html but in the response's header). Read this [answer](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/88714) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37927431/863110)

Comment: @Mosh Feu. Thanks.. Can you give me small idea for the reduce server response time. What is the best way?

Comment: It depends in a lot of things but you can google it. For example: https://varvy.com/pagespeed/improve-server-response.html

Comment: from the above page on the right , choose show original web page .

Answer (score 0):

Google weblight won't be appears on the light and fast website. So, the main key to disable permanently google weblight service is just make your website lighter and faster to load. There are many tricks to make your web lighter and faster than before. First, you can compress your web using gzip compress facility, avoid to use graphic, flash, or other media that can make your web slow to load, use CDN facility, and many other tricks you can try to speed up your website. You can prove it on my [official web](http://www.suaraguru.com/). Google weblight will never be appears on my official web after do all my tricks. Here I can give you full refference about how to do this.
[How to Disable Permanently Google Weblight Service from Your Website](http://www.suaraguru.com/topic-106-disable-google-web-light-dengan-cara-meningkatkan-load-speed-cdn-page-1.html)
May it's useful.

Comment: Okay, I'll update my answer, so please update your vote for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have implemented all these things. If You want then check my url in mobile.https://www.winni.in/cake-delivery-in-mumbai